# how to check a directory in a particular path not in CWD?

Tags: c++, c, linux, path

i know to check in the current directory `opendir(dir_name)` , but i need to check that in some other path , not in the `CWD(current working directory)`,

or is there any function is to move the **CWD** to some other directory while **executing**

Answer (score 2):

You could use `opendir(abs_path/dir_name)` to open a directory `dir_name` under absolute path `abs_path`.

You also could use `chdir()` to change your cwd to other directory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the daemon process change their directory to root while executing. The function to change the working directory while executing is chdir(PATH_TO_SET_AS_CWD).

Comment: "*the daemon process change their directory to root while executing.*" this is not necessarily the case. Please see `man daemon` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) for details.